# Read/Write to Cognito DeveloperOnlyAttribute

Tags: amazon-cognito

can someone provide some guidance how to read and write to the **DeveloperOnlyAttribute** as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-schemaattribute-developeronlyattribute)?

I've created this attribute using Cloudformation, and in the Cognito console, a custom attribute is created as `custom:dev:custom:paid_user`. If my understanding to the purpose of **DeveloperOnlyAttribute** is correct, my use case is, once user paid for the app, I'll have a back-end Lambda function that will change this attribute. User themselves will not have the authorization to change this attribute. Correct?

Thanks.

**Updated 2020/07**

The [aws document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SchemaAttributeType.html) has been updated with this line:

> We recommend that you use WriteAttributes in the user pool client to control how attributes can be mutated for new use cases instead of using DeveloperOnlyAttribute.

My use case scenario is that there are certain attributes that user can view, but **cannot** edit. Example `paid_user` attribute where after payment, the system will update this attribute; and user can never edit this attribute themself.

What I've done for my case is that I will set those attributes as `non-writtable` attributes. User will not be able to edit those attributes, but using `adminUpdateUserAttributes()` I'm still able to update them

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is close to zero information on this from the AWS documentation, but here's what I've discovered from testing myself.

Mutable DeveloperOnlyAttributes:

- always have a `dev:custom` prefix on them, except in the AWS console, where the prefix is `custom:dev:custom`. So in your case when using the apis you should be referring to the attribute as `dev:custom:paid_user`
- *are not* visible in a call to [`getUser()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property), regardless of whether it is called with developer credentials or not
- *are* visible when calling [`adminGetUser()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminGetUser-property). Calling this api requires developer credentials
- *are* editable when calling [`adminUpdateUserAttributes()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property). Calling this api requires developer credentials
- *are* editable when calling [`updateUserAttributes()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#updateUserAttributes-property), regardless of whether it is called with developer credentials or not

Re-read that last one for a moment. You don't need developer credentials to write to a DeveloperOnlyAttribute. A user can login with their username/password, and then make a call to `updateUserAttributes()` to change any DeveloperOnlyAttributes defined on their entry in the user pool. At least that's what my testing has shown, would love for somebody else to try this out and verify/disprove this behavior.

If cognito had a public bug tracker, this would go there.

Use at your own risk.

**UPDATE 2020/05**:

AWS Cognito has since contacted me privately to say they fixed the security issue outlined above.

Comment: Since there is *still* zero information available about any of this (or it's very well hidden), do you know if the `dev:` prefix is **only** there for DeveloperOnly attributes? Furthermore my intuition/tests so far suggest that mutability does not influence prefixes, do you know if that's correct?